# Is there a way to make mysql handle a large number of concurrent writes?

Tags: mysql, database, hbase

I'm stuck inbetween a rock and a hard place with an application I was making.  Basically the program generates a very large dataset(its over 10 gigs and exceeds memory on the server and its hard to transfer this dataset from a dictionary to other servers later on).  I decided to use a database to store the data but am running into a problem in which as I spawn more proceses they do not use more than 10% of its available core but the mysql service is always around 60-100%.

The core that is using mysql is running between 60-100%. I have taken basic mysql courses but am no way an expert on it and I'm really just using it to store/distribute local variables of the program.  Any suggestions of how I can troubleshoot or even if this problem is possible to solve? One idea I had was although my memory cannot store the entire database I plan to write, I would love for the server to use some memory to process some requests and then maybe write them as memory gets full(right now mysql is using less than 1% of server memory).

As you know my goal, I have no allegiance to any specific type of system so if mysql is not a good solution, I am happy to try another tool(I was going to use hbase, but went down the mysql road first). If anything else is better please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what you are actually trying to do but you'll need to provide a lot more information in order to get good advice.

What do you mean by large number of writes?  10?  100? 1000? per second?

What is the schema you are trying to write to?  What indexes are implemented on the schema?

Do you have heavy reads to writes or is this all writes?

What are you doing during your write? Is it a single row you are writing or is it a number of operations wrapped in a transaction?

What is the server configuration?  Memory?  Disk?  Version of mySQL.

Are you using Innodb for the database?

Now one thing you can try is to run SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;.  This will show you if there is some type of locking occurring - if you see a lot of the processes in a locked state, then look for one of the processes that is not locked and see if that may be causing locking.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-processlist.html for more info on this command.

Comment: I'm spawning 8 proceses so I think 8 writes a second. The table currently only has one column(it has to be unique). It has no indexes(thought that helped with reads not writes so didn't do anything). Its really two operations, its a read and if it doesn't exist to write to the database.  version is 5.1.61.  I'm not sure about configuration, its the default of centos 6 and I'm using Innodb. there is 11 rows of results when I looked at locked proceses and 2 of them are not locked(one is checking permissions and the other is writing to net).

Comment: I should add, the app is running on the same server as the database..I can move if needed. Server had 8 cores but SQL is maxing only 1 and app is taking less 10% so each core has 90 for MySQL

Comment: That really is nothing in terms of volume - mySQL can handle that in its sleep on a simple laptop computer.  Having no indexes is not a good thing, especially if you are doing a read before a write - without that index, mysql will do a complete table scan for each insert (with associated locks during that scan) - x6 per sec on a huge dataset can really chew your processes up.  I would recommend adding an index to the fields you are searching on first and see if that helps reduce contention.

Comment: Also, if your value you need to search is unique, you might consider simply creating a unique index and then dropping the search portion of the insert and then do your insert and if there is a conflict, your mysql driver will throw an error.  Not the prettiest, but it will help incrementally improve performance on the db end (although try/catch can be expensive on the app end).  However, you are nowhere near the type of volume that would justify this type of optimization.  Try the index suggestion first.

Comment: Thanks so much AlexGad.  I'll try the index and let you know(I was looking at the entire command not the single parts of it to figure out why it was slow).

Comment: Another thing I was thinking(I'll experiment with it) was, is chars slower than ints?  Basically I have a python dictionary with one number in each section (e.g.[1:5] or [2:10]) I'm uploading it as is right now into one column.  Would it make more sense to use two columsn one for each value?

Comment: I'm testing on a small set of data but without the index the code ran in 9 seconds, but with the index it ran in 12.

Comment: actually now its a bit better, my program is using 40-50% of the cpu now and mysql is using about the same 50-60%. It'll take a few hours to test full data but looks good.  Any other tips? Is integers better than chars for speed of reads/writes?

Comment: Depends how big your char is. Integers will usually be more compact thus less space, etc.  I would also recommend that you profile your queries and see what indexes are being used, etc.  That's usually the best way to determine what mysql is doing.  Without additional details, its hard to provide more info as to the best way to go.  One big suggestion I would make is to upgrade your mySQL to 5.5 as there were big improvements made between 5.1 and 5.5 on how processes get spread over multicores.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at upgrading.  Sorry I was wrong earlier, I was counting loops to get the queries/per second.  When I run mysqladmin status I get 10472.650 but the cpu usage is not high(and my database now is using memory as storage engine), but its still not completing quickly.  I have a combo of two columns that are a primary key and I also index those as well..

Comment: Does MySQL has something like Oracle's Index Organized Tables? If MySQL support it and you table is just a single column table (so you are indexing all the fields of the table), using an IOT is much better.

Comment: Really need more information at this point to help much more.  I would be suspicious of whether your inserts are occurring randomly.  Although you don't need it, might want to create an integer for an ID and create a clustered index on that to insure new records get tagged onto the end of the table.  Then you would create a secondary index on your text fields.

Comment: As good as StackOverflow is, I would also suggest that you bring this to the mySQL forums (http://forums.mysql.com/) so you can get more indepth help to really dig into what your issue might be.  For comparison sake, I just checked an app for a client to give you a benchmark - its running on 2 cores, inserting into a 10 column table that contains 250GB, and its completing 25 inserts per second without much sweat.  This sounds like its far more than what you are trying to accomplish on 9.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you just want to persist lots of data which is generated (or received) by your code, and you don't want to fetch them often (in this part of the code). If that's the case, and your data generation rate is so high, I recommend using a NoSQL database such as MongoDB instead of MySQL.
They are just created for large number of datasets, they are cluster-ready, and ... (just go to their documentations).

Comment: I'd disagree with the assumption that a NoSQL db is the way to go if you have a lot of data to persist.  Let's face it, Facebook did not get to where it got without persisting a lot of data to mySQL.  In my experience, mySQL can handle a ton of data, but like everything else, it needs to be used correctly.  I've used MongoDB and Redis and both excel in certain areas, but if mySQL has already been put in place, isn't it a better idea to figure out what is going wrong before moving off to something else which will have its own problems?

Comment: I'd also add that it was mentioned data was not fitting into memory.  It is very likely that the working set will not fit into memory under MongoDB as well.  If that is the case, then he will have even worse performance as Mongo really sucks wind if everything can't get into memory.  On top of that, high writes may be affected by Mongo's global write lock.  The way to get around that is with sharding, but now things are getting more complex.  As I mentioned, better to first figure out what the real problem is with the mySQL implementation before looking elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for both your advice..I really appreciate it(not trying to start a flame war or anything) but I really have no attachement to any particular solution just want something that fits my needs.  I was going to give hbase a try but wasn't sure if there was something to fix in mysql or if something else was better. I'll look into moogodb and answer @AlexGad's questions as I go through the mysql database and figure them out

Comment: Sorry if my comments came across as a flame war, definitely not trying to do that and apologize if that is the way it was taken.  I just wanted to point out that you can wind up trading one problem for another if you don't actually understand where the problem is in the first place.  Given the volume you are talking about, mySQL would be fine (as would mongo or redis or hbase).  If you want to move to either of those, you should not have any issues as the volume is low (6 inserts per sec) although you should understand the potential tradeoffs with all options.